# Findbugs or PMD rule to detect when StringBuffer should be replaced with StringBuilder

Tags: stringbuilder, findbugs, pmd, stringbuffer

Is there a rule in FindBugs or PMD that will warn when StringBuffer, which is synchronized, can be safely replaced with StringBuilder?

For example when a StringBuffer variable reference never escapes (to another Thread) from a method it would be possible to safely replace it with StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fb-contrib.sf.net  has one, called LocalSynchronizedCollections

this is a plugin for findbugs.

Comment: Looks useful (Detectors added in v2.4.0). The description talks about Collections. Does it work for StringBuffer?

Comment: yes, if you close your eyes and tilt your head to the side, a StringBuilder can be thought of as a collection of characters.